# onfocus not working with apex:inputField in chrome

Tags: visualforce, javascript, chrome

I had created a apex:inputField in my VF page and it was working fine. But when I checked this on chrome today, it didn't work. It is working fine on fire-fox but there seems to be an issue with chrome in calling onfocus event.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!exp.Type__c}" onfocus="onExpenseTypeFocus(this);" />
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Is there an error when you check the console?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this in my version of Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.101) and it seems fine...

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Test__c.Text__c}" 
         onfocus="this.style.background = 'red';" 
         onblur="this.style.background = 'white';"/>
```

[image]

[image]

Can you try usin the **Developer Tools** under the View > Developer menu, you may have some errors in your onExpenseTypeFocus method?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was facing this with picklist values in chrome. Actually, I was enabling and disabling all fields and it seems that chrome was getting in  an unknown situation due to this. I have now found a work-around for this. Again thanks for your reply.

Comment: Your welcome, glad you got it working! Do make sure to check if this answer was correct in respect to the question answered for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently upgrade Chrome? There is currently a known issue on displaying Visualforce pages on Chrome version 31.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1LRAA0